# At the time of Send SMS from dual sim Phone ask Which sim to send sms in Xamarin Android?

Tags: android, xamarin, sms

I am a `Xamarin` Android Developer. I am trying ​to send SMS from dual sim phone device. I need to ask to choose  either from SIM1 or SIM2 at the time of sending SMS.

But in xamarin the android code for send SMS

`SmsManager.Default.SendTextMessage (from1 [i]​, null, message, null, null);` ​

always chooses `DEFAULT SIM` of the mobile.

I tried the android code but its not supported in `Xamarin Android`. Please suggest  me the proper solution.

Comment: `I tried the android code but its not supported in Xamarin Android` ? What code is not supported?

Answer (score 0):

The dual SIM support is available from [Android 5.1](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/android-5.1.html#multisim) onwards. You may want to use the [SubscriptionManager](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/SubscriptionManager.html)

Comment: I already added it but still when am sending the sms my cant ask sim1 sim2 option .